# Question involving intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The function $g: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, is continuous, $g(1)>0$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$$

It is a fact that for every $y$ between $0$ and $g(1)$ the function takes on a value in $(\ y,\  g(1)\ )$

How would one show that if:

$$\lim_{e \to 0+}  \sup  \{g(x): 0<x<e\} =0 $$

then $g$ attains a maximum value on 0 to infinity.  Does $g$ necessarily have to be bounded below for this to hold?  Why?

Comment: What do you know about the set $\{ x : g(x) \geqslant g(1)\}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

- Since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$, there exists $R \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that for $x > R$, $g(x) < g(1)$.
- Since $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \sup\{g(x) : 0 < x < \epsilon\} = 0$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that for $x \in (0, r)$, $g(x) < g(1)$.
- $r < 1 < R$.
- The set $[r, R]$ is a compact set, and a continuous function on a compact domain achieves an absolute maximum on that domain.  This is the [Extreme Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).